# how can I make xUbuntu 16.04 recognize key combinations like Alt-Shift-5?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys

e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> is Strikeout in Google Docs. Pressing it just gives me the character `%`.

I do need the language switching combo <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, if you were going to suggest to disable it.

I've found patches for 17, but not for the version I'm using.

Thanks a lot.